# Rails 4, Active record strict search by arrays in associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

Given these models:

```
class Farm < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :animals
end

Class Animal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :farms
end
```

I need to search for `farms` that have `ducks`, `pigs` and `cows` but none of `cats` and `dogs`.

This kind of query doesn't work:

```
Animal.joins(:farms)
.where('animals.name IN ? AND animals.name NOT IN ?',
good_animal_names, bad_animal_names)
```

As it searches farms with ANY of the animals. I need to search farms that have ALL of the desired ones and none of the others.

I also tried with SQL with something like this:

```
SELECT farms.id, farms.name
FROM farms
INNER JOIN animals_farms ON animals_farms.farm_id = farms.id
INNER JOIN animals ON animals_farms.animal_id = animals.id
  WHERE animals.name IN (['ducks', 'pigs', 'cows'])
  AND  animals.name NOT IN (['dogs', 'cats'])
GROUP BY farms.id, farms.name
  HAVING COUNT(unique(animals.name)) = 3
```

But I'm not sure if `animals.name NOT IN` will really exclude farms that have none of the animals or only farms that don't have one of them. The real database is very difficult to verify the results.

Also, it should be great to be able to do the query in Active Record or Arel but any recommendation in SQL is more than welcome.

The database is Oracle, I don't have much experience with Oracle but most of the queries I use with PostgreSQL are working here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think I have a possible solution in SQL. Please, comment if you can see any issue or know a better way to do it.

```
WITH included_animals as (SELECT farms.id, farms.name
  FROM farms
  INNER JOIN animals_farms ON animals_farms.farm_id = farms.id
  INNER JOIN animals ON animals_farms.animal_id = animals.id
  WHERE animals.name IN ('ducks', 'pigs', 'cows')
  GROUP BY farms.id, farms.name
  HAVING COUNT(unique(animals.name)) = 3),
not_included_animals as (SELECT farms.id, farms.name
  FROM farms
  INNER JOIN animals_farms ON animals_farms.farm_id = farms.id
  INNER JOIN animals ON animals_farms.animal_id = animals.id
  WHERE animals.name IN ('dogs', 'cats')
  GROUP BY farms.id, farms.name)
SELECT id, name
FROM included_animals
MINUS --use EXCEPT if riding PostgreSQL
SELECT id, name
FROM not_included_animals
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have only two categories of animals -(good/bad), and you need only good animals. Can you try this?

`Farm.joins(:animals).where.not(animals: {name: bad_animal_names})`

Hope it helps!

Comment: It will list all other animals other than bad animals is what it meant . Please try it by running in your app

Comment: second way to do: `Farm.joins(:animals).where(animals: {name: good_animal_names})`

Comment: @uDaY there is a many-to-many relationship between farms and animals, the queries that you provided assume that the farm will only ever have the 5 animals the OP listed in the question.